# Can a fixed point combinator find the fixed point of a function that has no fixed point?

Tags: lambda-calculus

A [fixed point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) is supposed to find the fixed point of any function. Yet I am wondering what if a function happens to have no fixed point, such as the `add1` function over $\mathbb{Z}$, mapping -1 to 0, 0 to 1, etc. Does the fixed point combinator make sense any more?

Comment: Welcome to TCS StackExchange!  This forum is for *research-level* questions on theoretical computer science.  Your question is better suited for [CS StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).  A quick answer: if your language is total (everything terminates), then there is no fixpoint combinator.  Therefore, the very existence of a fixpoint combinator implies the existence of partial (nonterminating) functions, hence the existence of a $\bot$ (undefined) element in any type, including $\mathbb Z$.  In the case you mention, the fixpoint of $\mathtt{add1}$ is precisely $\bot$.